# As of Date Logic In Cognos

Tags: sql, db2, cognos, cognos-8

I'm working in Cognos 10.1.1

I have requirement for 62 list reports that differ by columns.

If we group them based of the category, 31 reports show BOD and 31 show EOD data.

EOD (T-2 data) and BOD (T-1 data).

Here is the requirement.  In order to reduce the number of reports we have planned to mingle these two date logics in a single reports.

```
Case 
   when [Time Selection] = 'EOD' then
      [As of date] = _add_days(current_date,-2) 
   else 
      [As of date] = _add_days(current_date,-1) 
end
```

This works fine but there is some decrease in the report performance.  It is running longer than the separate reports.

I tried using a macro but there is no difference between the above case condtion and the macro when the sql is generated.

Please suggest me a solution to increase the report performance.

We are using db2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what about running them in separate queries and unioning the results together?

Comment: We need more information, like what the rest of the query looks like, and what's generated by cognos.  I have a feeling that the `CASE` _may_ be run for every row, which isn't going to help any.  A naïve optimization of that is likely to end up with an `OR` condition, which optimizers aren't too happy with either (but may still help)...

Comment: Normally you are querying based on date, but with the EOD/BOD change, you are first querying based on your EOD flag.  You should check your table indexes.  You likely have one on date, but not one on your EOD flag.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code without knowing your issue, I wouldn't suspect that your code would produce a performance problem. That said I avoid using =, <> etc. when working with dates. Instead, I use the built-in date math functions.

Try the following:

```
CASE 
   WHEN [Time Selection] = 'EOD' THEN
      _days_between([As of date],current_date) = -1
   ELSE
      _days_between([As of date],current_date) = -2
END
```

There is also another syntax that may also perform better than your existing code. We can eliminate the CASE statement and use simple boolean logic in your filter:

```
([Time Selection] = 'EOD' AND _days_between([As of date],current_date) = -1)
OR
([Time Selection] <> 'EOD' AND _days_between([As of date],current_date) = -2)
```

This syntax takes advantage of an optimization in most languages, including SQL, where if the first term of an AND returns false the line is skipped without evaluating the second term as the result of the AND could never be true.

Comment: Why would you avoid range operators?  For one thing, using a function on a column is the fastest way to stop an index from being used - there's no way the optimizer can seek on an index, it has to run over **all** the entries first.  Whereas if you use range queries (and date math on a constant value, like `CURRENT_ DATE`), it can index seek/scan, potentially speeding queries up greatly.  [The only range operator to avoid with date types is `<=`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), like all positive non-integral types.

Comment: I didn't say anything about a range operator, plus or minus. I gave him two alternate syntaxes that may or may not alleviate his performance problem. If you think you have a better solution then you should post an answer.

Comment: The case statement is not the cause of any performance issues. It will perform 1k times faster than any I/O it makes unnecessary. So if the one query is running slower than the two queries individually, the problem is not in the case statement. Look at the execution plan and find out where the most time is being spent.

Provide the individual queries, entire replacement query and a layout of the table(s) involved, and I'll bet there is something as simple as an index that will make it work wonders.